# Loading assembly with reflection - 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Description'?

Tags: c#, mongodb, dynamic, reflection

We need to load mongodb c# assembly at runtime.

( *reason: health check service attached to an app via nuget , needs to check the app for mongo connectivity, but it should use the existing(!) mongo dll in the BIN. Not bringing one of its own, Hence loading mongo by reflection*)

All I need to check is this code :

```
  MongoClient client = new MongoClient(mongoConnection);
  var res = client.Cluster.Description.State == ClusterState.Connected;
```

I've managed to do the first part:

```
Assembly dll = Assembly.LoadFile(@"C:\Users\RoyiNamir\....\MongoDB.Driver.dll");
Type type = dll.GetType("MongoDB.Driver.MongoClient");
Console.WriteLine(type); //MongoDB.Driver.MongoClient

dynamic client = Activator.CreateInstance(type, mongoConnection);
Console.WriteLine(client.Cluster.Description );
```

I get an exception on the last line , where I try to print `client.Cluster.Description` :

[image]

```
Message
'object' does not contain a definition for 'Description' 

Source
Anonymously Hosted DynamicMethods Assembly 

StackTrace
   at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object )
   at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute1[T0,TRet](CallSite site, T0 arg0)
   at UserQuery.Main()
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

But - if I execute `Console.WriteLine(client.Cluster);` instead , then I do get result :

[image: SingleServerCluster]

Using reflector, I see that [Description](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver/blob/master/src/MongoDB.Driver.Core/Core/Clusters/ICluster.cs#L53) is :

```
ClusterDescription Description { get; }
```

Where [ClusterDescription](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver/blob/master/src/MongoDB.Driver.Core/Core/Clusters/ClusterDescription.cs#L29) is :

```
  public sealed class ClusterDescription : IEquatable<ClusterDescription> {}
```

**Question:**

Why does the exception is being thrown?
Using dynamic/reflection, How can I access the `Description` property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the class  implements the `Description` property explicitly. Thus your code should look like this in order to fix it. That is, you need to explicitly cast to the correct interface.

```
    dynamic c =Activator.CreateInstance(type);
    Console.WriteLine(((ICluster)c.Cluster).Description);
```

Or you can go with all dynamic like below:

```
 dynamic c =Activator.CreateInstance(type);
var targetType = type.GetProperties().Where(x => x.Name == "Cluster").Single().PropertyType;
Console.WriteLine(targetType.GetProperty("Description").GetValue(c.Cluster));
```

Comment: what I mean is this : https://i.imgur.com/HX6wyDu.jpg . I don't have ICluster since all should be loaded at runtime via reflection.

Comment: I have updated the code to meet your requirements of all dynamic :)

Comment: Working my friend : https://i.imgur.com/iOhLimw.jpg

Comment: BTW where did you see that _the class implements the Description property explicitly.`_?

Comment: I knew from the behavior of reflection